# Using Access 2007 Queries From VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I have a access database setup which i am connecting to via ODBC, the access files already has all the required queries built and i would simple like to call them from within my application.

I am using Visual Basic .NET and this is what i have tried so far.....

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Ben

```
        Dim command As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand

    command.Connection = cnx
    command.CommandText = "sp_InsertClient"
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    '//====== create ABN paramenter =============
    Dim param1 As OdbcParameter = New OdbcParameter("inABN", abn)
    param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    param1.DbType = DbType.String
    'add abn parameter
    command.Parameters.Add(param1)

   Dim dataAdapter As OdbcDataAdapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(command)

    dataAdapter.InsertCommand = command
    Try
        cnx.Open()
        dataAdapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Sub
    Finally
        cnx.Close()
    End Try


    MessageBox.Show("DONE")
```

Answer (score 0):

So, what is your question?

Looking at the code above, you shouldn't need a dataAdapter.
You could call `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` to do the work.

EDIT: Also, you could wrap the OdbcConnection & OdbcCommand in a `using...end using` block.

Comment: Sorry i should have explained more, i removed the dataAdapter and just used command.ExecuteNonQuery() but still the same error

Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

My question is what could be wrong with the code as the query works from within access.

Comment: Edit the code & show what you have as of now alongwith code from the sp_Insert.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the VB Code

```
Public Sub AddClient(ByVal abn As String, ByVal companyName As String, _
                     ByVal contactName As String, ByVal phoneNumber As String, _
                     ByVal address As String)
    'Dim command As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand
    Using cnx As New OdbcConnection(My.Settings.connectionString)
        Using command As New OdbcCommand
            command.Connection = cnx
            command.CommandText = "sp_InsertClient"
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            '//====== create ABN paramenter =============
            Dim param1 As OdbcParameter = New OdbcParameter("inABN", abn)
            param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            param1.DbType = DbType.String
            'add abn parameter
            command.Parameters.Add(param1)

            '//====== create CompanyName Parameter ================
            Dim param2 As OdbcParameter = New OdbcParameter("inCompanyName", companyName)
            param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            param2.DbType = DbType.String
            'add the parameter
            command.Parameters.Add(param2)

            '//======== create ContactName Param ===============
            Dim param3 As OdbcParameter = New OdbcParameter("inContactName", contactName)
            param3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            param3.DbType = DbType.String
            'add the parameter
            command.Parameters.Add(param3)

            '//=========== create PhoneNumber Parameter ===============
            Dim param4 As OdbcParameter = New OdbcParameter("inPhoneNumber", phoneNumber)
            param4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            param4.DbType = DbType.String
            'add paramater
            command.Parameters.Add(param4)

            '//=========== create Address Parameter ===============
            Dim param5 As OdbcParameter = New OdbcParameter("inAddress", address)
            param5.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            param5.DbType = DbType.String
            'add paramater
            command.Parameters.Add(param5)

            Try
                cnx.Open()
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", _
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

                Exit Sub
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show("DONE")
End Sub
```

And here is my query in Access.

```
INSERT INTO tblClients ( ABN, CompanyName, ContactName, PhoneNumber, Address )
VALUES ([inABN], [inCompanyName], [inContactName], [inPhoneNumber], [inAddress]);
```

Thanks for all the help...

Answer (score 0):

*Edited my old answer... it was wrong*

According to [this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article.aspx?ArticleID=26) and [this](http://forums.asp.net/p/1359561/2802270.aspx#2802270), you're doing it right.

An alternative to using prebuilt queryies in access is to define them as Stored Procedures in access. [Working with MS Access Stored Procedures in VB.NET. Part 1](http://www.devcity.net/Articles/34/msaccess_sp2.aspx) is a good overview of this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for them links i had seen them already but had missed the adding of EXECUTE, that seems to be getting the queries to run now, but my parameters are not been passed to the access query.

I have tested and my parameters are been added to the command but not to the access query?

I also tried Parameters.AddWithValue("paramname", value)

but this was the same result

Also i changed my query in access to this, turns out the square brackets where not needed...

> INSERT INTO tblClients ( ABN, CompanyName, ContactName, PhoneNumber, Address )
>   VALUES (inABN, inCompanyName, inContactName, inPhoneNumber, inAddress)

Thanks
Ben